# pyproject.toml setuptools: How can I specify optional scripts (and modules)?

Tags: python, setuptools, dependency-management, pyproject.toml

I have a python project with some modules, scripts and optional dependencies:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
extra = [ "tqdm", "antspyx>=0.4.2", "scikit-image", "mpi4py", "scipy" ]

[project.scripts]
reg = "myproject._cmd.reg:main"
conv = "myproject._cmd.conv:main"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["myproject*"]
```

Now I would like the scripts to be installed, only for `pip install myproject[extra]`. By now, these scripts are installed even for `pip install myproject`

It would also be nice to be able to split my modules like this. Modules in `src/myproject/extra/` should be installed only for `pip install myproject[extra]`. If `pip install myproject` is called, only modules in `src/myproject/modules/` should be installed.

So, how can I declare optional modules and optional scripts in pyproject.toml?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and I couldn't find a solution that doesn't require a setup.py file. Have you found something in the meantime?

Comment: Got the same issue here. The [setuptools doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies) talks about *extra dependencies* and redirects to the [entry-points](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/) spec, but it seems like setuptools yet doesn't implement that feature. As a workaround you could use something like this in the `__init__.py` of the sub-package needed the dependency:

`try:  import yourExtraPackage except ImportError: raise SystemExit("ERROR MESSAGE FOR THE USER HERE")`